# Forbidden Archive during Wine Installation

Tags: software-installation, wine, synaptic

I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 along windows 10 on a separate drive.

I installed all previous packages. But when I attempted to install `wine`, it failed(though I was able to install it in my old Ubuntu 14.04) giving following message on synaptic manager.

```
E: Unable to correct missing packages   
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxxf86vm/libxxf86vm1_1.1.3-1_i386.deb 403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
```

I have noticed that `libxxf86vm` is inaccessible from my pc.

How can I install wine?

Comment: Did you do sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade before attempting to install wine? Also try sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

Comment: Yes, i followed instructions on https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu with your suggestion but it gives the same error without installing wine. Is http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxxf86vm access-able elsewhere?

Comment: Try this, purge the wine PPA, restart your computer, sudo apt-get update (and upgrade) then install wine from a PPA not from synaptics ;-) . I am not sure about the package libxxf86vm

Comment: I followed your instructions with a repeat of error.

Comment: I used my private mobile network and it worked. It appears that my institute had blocked access to some Ubuntu archives.

Comment: Happy to hear that it worked for you :-)